# How to send phpunit errors to Laravel log channels? i.e. slack?

Tags: laravel-5, slack, phpunit, laravel-dusk2

we are implementing functional testing in our Laravel app environment and we want the results of phpunit dusk tests to be logged in a slack channel via webhook. Anyone?

We achieved to log results in single files as described in documentation (using phpunit --log-TypeOfLog) but we want to receive notifications when we run that tests in automated mode in other channels.

We can manually send notifications to slack (or other channels) if we put `Log::error('Something happened!');` but we want this to be automatically done when tests finish.

Comment: So, you're looking for a way to call a URL after the phpUnit has finished and send the results in it (in the request)

Comment: Hi, or to use the integrated notifications system of Laravel that is already sending messages to slack, but not tests results. The problem is that now we only see the test results in the terminal window so we can't automate the process to be alerted if something fails.

Comment: By the way, you cant integrate laravel into the tests easily, you are `testing laravel with phpunit`, not using laravel to control phpunit to test laravel. you can however launch laravel to check the results afterward but wouldnt recommand it. if a test fails, your script to send the test results may fail as well for the same cause

Answer (score 0):

You can run the command for phpunit like this

```
(vendor/bin/)phpunit |grep Failures > failed_tests.txt
```

Then after that cron run another that checks if the file `failed_tests.txt` is not empty. If so send it with mail and empty/delete/archive it